# Batch file download and run multiple files, one by one?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I'm trying to create a batch file that can download and run three files one at a time. Two of them are .bat files and one an .exe file. I'm trying to use powershell commands for this within a .bat file as it needs to be executable. I'm struggling with this as I'm unfamiliar with both batch files and powershell.

```
PowerShell.exe -Command "$url = "https://ufile.io/wqtvx""
PowerShell.exe -Command "$outpath = "$PSScriptRoot/downloadtest.bat""
PowerShell.exe -Command "Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $outpath"
PowerShell.exe -Command "$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient"
PowerShell.exe -Command "$wc.DownloadFile($url, $outpath)"
PowerShell.exe -Command "$args = @("Comma","Separated","Arguments")"
PowerShell.exe -Command "Start-Process -Filepath "$PSScriptRoot/downloadtest.bat" -ArgumentList $args"
```

The above code will be repeated three times for each file I'd like to download. I am not very sure where to store the file I'd like to download online so I uploaded it to a free file storage website. If anyone can help me get this working I'd appreciate it.

Comment: You are starting separate powershell processes. Variables defined in each of them will be lost.

Comment: May you please correct the code for me so I can compare and try to understand the issue?

Comment: check [this](https://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=2315)

Comment: Add commands separated by `; `.

Comment: Also, the download fails when it tries to access that link. Not sure where to store the target file...

Comment: Also in the last comman the used `"` will most likely result in an error since you use them for encapsulating the command itself and the path inside that command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem with this script is that the `powershell.exe -c` command will only run the code after it on one iteration of powershell. Once it's finished running the code, it "Closes" that powershell window (Trying to explain it simple as possible).

Powershell has the ability to link commands on a simple command line, similar to batches `&` symbol, powershell has the `;` for this job. Furthermore, your code still would not have worked as stated by James C. - The link isn't direct to the file, it requires you to 'click' a button to initializes the download.

Not to advertise but I suggest GitHub or MediaFire as you can get direct download links to each file. No javascript interaction needed on the webpage to download them.

---

This script will put most of your commands on a single line, thus allowing the download from powershell. This particular command will work on all vs 1.0+ of powershells. A simple `start Batchfile.bat` takes care of the rest or you can go on to add onto the command by adding `; Start-Process -Filepath $PSScriptRoot/downloadtest.bat -ArgumentList exc`...

```
Powershell.exe -Command "(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://Site/Batchfile.bat', '%~dp0downloadtest.bat')"
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! Will use Github :)

Comment: This worked, thanks! How do I specify a path where to save the downloaded file though?

Comment: @Mike Change the `'%~dp0downloadtest.bat'` To The path you want. This is the outpath. The `%~dp0` is simply the batch file location. PS: If this was a solution please use the green checkmark so others know! Good luck.

Comment: The '%~dp0downloadtest.bat' is strictly the name and cannot be used as the directory. Will do - thanks.

Comment: @Mike Yes the path can be like `C:\downloadtest.bat`, `C:\folder\batch.bat` or other. Just make sure you put the name with it at the end. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

You are starting a separate Powershell process on each line, so each line is completely unaffected by the other.  This won't work, since you're defining variables and assigning values to them on one line, then trying to use them later in an entirely separate process which has no such variable. The simplest answer is to separate all of your statements by semicolons as mentioned by [double-beep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10607772/double-beep).

```
PowerShell.exe -Command "$url = 'https://ufile.io/wqtvx'; $outpath = '$PSScriptRoot/downloadtest.bat'; Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $outpath; $wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient; $wc.DownloadFile($url, $outpath); $args = @('Comma','Separated','Arguments'); Start-Process -Filepath '$PSScriptRoot/downloadtest.bat' -ArgumentList $args"
```

Note you have misused quotation marks in your code. Look at the syntax highlighting for an idea as to what's going on in your first line:

```
PowerShell.exe -Command "$url = "https://ufile.io/wqtvx""
```

Powershell will interpret your command as the first string, "$url = ", which will return an error because it's not valid Powershell syntax. Then https://ufile.io/wqtvx is outside of any quotes, and Powershell will again have no idea how to interpret this and throw an error. Finally, you have the empty string "" tacked onto the end, which adds no meaning whatsoever to the statement. Use single quotes for quotes within quotes as shown in my example above.

Generally, this much code is too much for a one liner. It's difficult to read and troubleshoot. I would suggest creating a Powershell script, which is just a text file with a .ps1 file extension, and naming it something like "DownloadFile.ps1".  In that file, put the following code:

```
$url = "https://ufile.io/wqtvx"
$outpath = "$PSScriptRoot/downloadtest.bat"
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $outpath
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.DownloadFile($url, $outpath)
$args = @("Comma","Separated","Arguments")
Start-Process -Filepath "$PSScriptRoot/downloadtest.bat" -ArgumentList $args
```

Then call that from your batch file with something like:

```
Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "C:\Path\To\DownloadFile.ps1"
```

Comment: Unfortunately this needs to be one file that does everything, but thanks for all the information! Will definitely help and will keep you posted with my progress.

Answer (score 0):

Each powershell process is separate and know what has been done in another, you need to either include all your code in a single `-Command` param, or use the `-File` and pass it a multi line powershell script.

Also your download will fail as that link isn't direct to the file, it requires you to 'click' a button to initialise the download.

Because of this you will get a `downloadtest.bat` that contains the HTML source for the *download page itself*.

---

Once you have a filehost with a direct URL link, you can use a semicolon `;` between the two commands `Invoke-WebRequest` and `Start-Process` so they are on a single line:

```
PowerShell.exe -Command "Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://filehost.com/directlink/downloadtest.bat -OutFile $PSScriptRoot/downloadtest.bat ; Start-Process -Filepath $PSScriptRoot/downloadtest.bat -ArgumentList @('Comma','Separated','Arguments')"
```